# respone.sendRedirect() works fine in firefox but not in IE6

Tags: jsp, servlets, internet-explorer-6

I have a servlet that redirects to a jsp page using response.sendRedirect(),
It works fine in firefox, but in IE6 it does not redirect to this page. Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/443561/Servlets/java/sendRedirect-working.

```
public void editQuery() throws IOException {  
  String url = request.getContextPath() + "/search.jsp";  
  url = response.encodeRedirectURL(url);  
  //url = response.encodeURL(url);  
  response.setHeader("Pragma", "No-cache");  
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");  
  response.setHeader("Expires", "1");  
  response.sendRedirect(url);
}
```

**Please note that IE6 is no longer maintained.** Microsoft publishes no security fixes which makes this a very unsafe browser.

Comment: Agree about IE6. It would, in fact, be better to not fix this, instead stating clearly that the application does not support IE6.

Comment: And I thought my application was horrible. Needs support in IE8